# My tags that I actually edited

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits

I have two question about editing tags:

1. How to list or see my tags that I edited?
2. How to know if my edit is accepted or rejected?

Comment: you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/youcef-laidani?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: I see, thank you @RobertLongson

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see a list of suggested edits (including tag edits) in your profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/ycf-l?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Note that you can't filter out the suggested edits on posts, but once you reach [2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) that's no longer a problem.

For the list of tags you edited, you can just look at the approved edits in this list, but once you reach [20k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) you probably need to use something like this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/552374/tags-that-i-edited), because tag edits are then no longer subject to approval.

```sql
SELECT t.tagname,
  CASE t.excerptpostid WHEN h.postid THEN 'Excerpt' ELSE 'Wiki' END,
  h.creationdate, h.text, h.comment
  FROM posthistory AS h
  INNER JOIN tags AS t
    ON t.excerptpostid = h.postid
    OR t.wikipostid = h.postid
  WHERE userid = ##UserId##
  ORDER BY creationdate DESC
```

Note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.